# Validation failed for parameter 'id'. Invalid number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, ssms

I'm connecting my Node backend(connected the database using Microsoft SQL Server) to React front-end. Note: The backend works great and tested with postman for all endpoints.

While connecting to it, throws me this error : **"Validation failed for parameter 'id'. Invalid number.**"

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Events from "./components/Events";

const App = () => {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEvents = async () => {
      const res = await axios(
        `http://localhost:8080/api/event/${setSearchQuery}`
      );
      console.log(res.data);
      setCustomers(res.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchEvents();
  }, [searchQuery]);
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      <Search getQuery={(sq) => setSearchQuery(sq)} />
      <Events isLoading={isLoading} customers={customers} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Event.js**

```
import  React from "react";

const Event = ({ customer }) => {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-inner">
                <div className="card-front">
                    <img src={customer.img} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="card-back">
                    <h1>{customer.id}</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Customer ID:</strong> {customer.id}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Customer Number:</strong> {customer.Cus_no}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Range Name:</strong> {customer.RangeName}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Color:</strong> {customer.Color}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Blade Text:</strong> {customer.BladeTExt}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Special Notes:</strong> {customer.SpecialNotes}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <strong>Box Quantity:</strong> {customer.box_qty}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Event;
```

**Events.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Event from "./Event";
import Spinner from "./Spinner.js";

const Events = ({ customers, isLoading }) => {
    return isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
    ) : (
        <section className="cards">
            {customers.map((customer) => (
                <Event key={customer.id} customer={customer}></Event>    //key={customer.id}
            ))}
        </section>
    );
};

export default Events;
```

**Search.js**

```
import  React, { useState } from "react";

const Search = ({ getQuery }) => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

    const onChange = (sq) => {
        setNumber(sq);
        getQuery(sq);
    };

    return (
        <section className="search">
            <form>
                <input
                    type="Number"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Search Customer Numbers"
                    value={number}
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
                    autoFocus
                />
            </form>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Search;
```

For better understanding here is a Sample SQL Table output with the data types I created : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c925fb80326b4c3ed2117beddb73b451

Now comes the great part, whenever I use the endpoint "http://localhost:8080/api/events" the whole customer data set displays correctly as it supposed to. But for the endpoint "http://localhost:8080/api/event/${setSearchQuery}" it gives me the error.

Comment: It sounds like something is going wrong on your backend in your validation? Hard to tell without seeing the backend code. I would have thought you would have taped it together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
```

your backend API for fetching event needs an id for it and when every your component mounts to the dom, your `useEffect` kicks in and calls the API! but meanwhile your state of `searchQuery` is an empty string!

NOTE:

```
const res = await axios(
  `http://localhost:8080/api/event/${setSearchQuery}`
);
```

you are using `setSearchQuery` in your endpoint string instead of `searchQuery`!

that being said, I think still you will get an error even after changing that bug in your URL! because you still send an empty string as id for your backend API!

So the best solution would be to provide a default id for your `searchQuery` in your `useState` instead of passing an empty string, or if you cannot provide a default value, make sure that your api does not broke when you providing empty string to it!